# Can arbitrary values be reached by repeatedly adding or subtracting a fixed percentage of the current value?

Tags: percentages

Let $G$ and $X$ be positive integers, and $P$ be a rational value in $(0, 1)$. Two operations may be performed on $X$ to modify its value:

$$X \leftarrow \lfloor X \cdot (1 + P) \rfloor$$ and $$X \leftarrow \lfloor X \cdot (1 - P) \rfloor$$

Is it possible, by repeatedly applying these operations, to make $X = G$? What conditions are necessary for a solution to exist?

For a more concrete example: Let $G = 100$, $X = 50$, $P = 0.1$. Is $X = 100$ possible after a finite number of steps, where in each step $10\%$ of $X$ is either added or subtracted from $X$?

Comment: Very nice question! :)

Comment: This seems like a job for group theory!

Comment: Maybe use recursion instead of arrow. In math the programming $X=SomeFunction(X);$ would be $x_0=a$ and $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$.

Comment: If $G=2,X=1,p=0.9$, there is no solution, because $\lfloor 1*(1+0.9) \rfloor = \lfloor 1.9 \rfloor = 1$, $\lfloor 1*(1-0.9) \rfloor = \lfloor 0.1 \rfloor = 0$ and $\lfloor 0*(1 \pm 0.9) \rfloor = 0$

Comment: @Peter I should clarify that I'm also interested in the conditions necessary for a solution to exist.

Comment: I *think* that $X\ge \frac 1P$ might be sufficient ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $p\in(0,1)$ such that $\frac{\ln(1+p)}{\ln(1-p)}$ is irrational.

For $(a,b,c)\in\Bbb N^3$ with $b<c$, let
$$ F(a,b,c)=\begin{cases}\bigl(\lfloor (1+p)a\rfloor, b, c\bigr)&\text{if }a<b,\\
\bigl(a,\lceil\frac b{1-p}\rceil, \lceil\frac c{1-p}\rceil\bigr)&\text{if } c\le a,\\(a,b,c)&\text{if }b\le a<c \end{cases}$$

> **Theorem.**
>   If $a,b,c\in\Bbb N$ with $b<c$, then the sequence $\{F^{\circ n}(a,b,c)\}_n$ is eventually stationary.

*[Incomplete] Proof.*
Let $(a_n,b_n,c_n)=F^{\circ n}(a,b,c)$.
If ever $b_n\le a_n<c_n$, we are done. 
If $a_0<\frac1p$ and ever $b_n>a_n$ for the first time, then $a_n=a_0$ and $\lfloor(1+p)a_n\rfloor = a_n$ and we are done.
So assume otherwise.$a_0\ge \frac 1p$ and never $b_n\le a_n<c_n$.
As $\lceil\frac c{1-p}\rceil \ge \frac c{1-p}>b$, we will eventually have $c_n>a_n$ and hence $a_n<b_n$ for some $n$. Thus $F$ takes the first branch infinitely often and $a_n\to +\infty$.
But then also $b_n\to+\infty$ and $c_n\to+\infty$.

**Claim:** $q:=\liminf\frac{c_n}{b_n}>1$. (???)

Now let $x_n=\frac{a_n}{b_n}$. Then we have $$x_{n+1}\approx \begin{cases}(1+p)x_n&\text{if }x_n<1\\(1-p)x_n&\text{if }x_n>1\end{cases}$$ and the error hidden in the "$\approx$" tends to $0$ as $n\to\infty$.
As $\frac{\ln(1+p)}{\ln(1-p)}$ is irrational, this implies that infintiely many $x_n$ are close to any given $\alpha$ with $1<\alpha<1+p$. In particular, we will find ininfitely mayn $n$ with $1<x_n<\frac{1+q}2$, hence some $n$ with $1<\frac {a_n}{b_n}<\frac{c_n}{b_n}$. Then $F(a_n,b_n,c_n)=(a_n,b_n,c_n)$. $\square$(modulo claim)

> **Corollary.** If  $X,G\in \Bbb N$ and $X\ge\frac 1p$, then a finite sequence of applications of $f_+\colon x\mapsto \lfloor (1+p)x\rfloor$ and/or $f_-\colon x\mapsto \lfloor (1-p)x\rfloor$ takes $X$ to $G$.

*Proof.*
Let $(a_0,b_0,c_0)=(X,G,G+1)$ and define recursively $(a_{n+1},b_{n+1},c_{n+1})=F(a_n,b_n,c_n)$.
by the theorem above, there is some minimal $n$ with $(a_{n+1},b_{n+1},c_{n+1})=(a_{n},b_{n},c_{n})$.
As $F$ is  component-wise non-decreasing, we conclude $a_n\ge a_{n-1}\ge\ldots \ge X$, and  $b_n\ge \ldots \ge G$.
From $a_n\ge \frac1p$, we see $\lfloor (1+p)a_n\rfloor \ge a_n+1$, hence $F(a_n,b_n,c_n)=(a_n,b_n,c_n)$ implies $a_n\ge b_n$.
Likewise. $\lceil\frac {b_n}{1-p}\rceil >b_n$ implies that $c_n>a_n$, so that $b_n\le a_n<c_n$.

Whenever $F(a_n,b_n,c_n)$ takes the first branch, we have $a_{n+1}=f_+(a_n)$.
Note that $f_-(x)\ge y\iff x\ge \frac y{1-p}$; hence whenever $F(a_n,b_n,c_n)$ takes the second branch, we have $b_n\le f_-(x)<c$ for all $x$ with $b_{n+1}\le x<c_{n+1}$. 
Let $k=\{\,i\mid 0\le i<n,a_{i+1}>a_i\,\}$. 
Then $f_+^{\circ k}(a_0)=a_n$ and $b_0\le f_-^{\circ(n-k)}(x)<c_0$ whenever $b_n\le x<c_n$. So from $b_n\le a_n<c_n$ we conclude
$$f_-^{\circ(n-k)}f_+^{\circ k}(X)=G.$$
$\square$

Comment: To make sure I understand this correctly: $X \ge \frac{1}{p}$ and $\frac{ln(1+p)}{ln(1-p)} \in \Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$ are necessary and sufficient conditions for taking $X$ to $G$ with the repeated application of the operations?

Answer (score 0):

This is a concrete answer to the more concrete question: $100$ can be reached from $50$ with $P=1/10$:
\begin{align}
50\to55\to60\to66\to72\to79\to71\to78\to85&\to76\to83\to91\to100\\
&\to93\to83\to91\to100\\
&\phantom{\to93}\to102\to91\to100
\end{align}
These are the shortest chains leading to $100$.